# Как закрывать приложение из шторки, нажатием на крестик

Tags: java, android, android-service, уведомления, android-notification

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как закрывать открытое приложение по нажатию на крестик, как например это реализовано в приложении Вконтакте., когда играет музыка, и в шторке можно нажать на крестик. Буду признателен, если хотя бы подскажите где и куда копать))

[image]

Comment: ума не могу приложить, о каком крестике вы говорите ? приведите скрин хоть для наглядности

Comment: @LexHobbit, добавил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что изображено у Вас на скриншоте – это уведомление от [foreground-сервиса](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground).

Из этого уведомления Вы можете управлять сервисом:

1. Остановить сервис – `stopSelf();`. При этом уведомление тоже пропадет.
2. Убрать уведомление (сделать сервис background-сервисом) – `stopForeground(true);`. Сервис при этом продолжит свою работу.